# Mod Rewrite Rule to take article ID from URL and place a Slash before it

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, friendly-url

I have a wordpress site which has hundreds of articles with URLs in the following format:

```
http://www.example.com/news/variable-article-name-XXXXXXXXX/
```

where `XXXXXXXXX` is always a 9 digit number

I'd like to rewrite the URLs to include a slash before the number; to appear as follows.

```
http://www.example.com/news/variable-article-name/XXXXXXXXX/
```

Is there a simple, single rule I can write to achieve this?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
RewriteRule ^news/(.*)-(\d{9})/?$ /news/$1/$2 [R=301,L]
```

You'd still need some internal rewrite so that the redirected URL can be forwarded to appropriate pages.